# Use material-ui and react in sandbox such as CodePen

Tags: reactjs, sandbox, material-ui

I would like to sandbox material-ui components for testing/experimentation, I see that it only comes as an npm package.

Codepen makes it easy to use Babel, but the `imports` statement does not seem to work. On a Pro account you are given file assets, but these are only accessable via http:// references.

There is [Create a tool to build a standalone version of Material-UI](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/262) but thats all I can find in this direction.

I am interested in ideas and approaches, even difficult ones, that would accomplish the goal of getting material-ui in a web-based sandbox.

Comment: Very roundabout method;  Set up a simple web server that downloads the npm packages and feeds them out through http access.  Include your custom mini server resources as a file import on codepen.  Profit?

Comment: You can try http://www.webpackbin.com/ which allows npm modules

Answer (score 0):

Work in progress: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/4342

(SO says I must write more.)